# Redirecionar todas as requisições de mídia(css,js e imagens) com htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess

Estou construindo uma aplicação MVC e estava tendo alguns problemas com o caminho dos arquivos **css,js e imagens** no html... foi me dada uma solução de usar a tag `<base>` para definir o caminho que todos os arquivos do html seguiriam, ex: `<base href="http://localhost/mvc/>`, só que de lá pra cá tive alguns problemas para instalar plugins javascript, uma vez que quando eu colocava, por exemplo, `href="#"` que ao clicar em vez de não fazer ação nenhuma, esse link me levava pra a url que foi definida com a tag `<base>` que seria `http://localhost/mvc/#`, gostaria de saber como posso redirecionar todos os "requests" desses arquivos à uma subpasta, ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<img src="images/img2.jpg" />
```

Todas as requisições levariam para uma subpasta, por exemplo, **PUBLIC**, ai só precisaria definir no html as pastas dentro dessa **public**...

Arquivo HTACCESS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Testou algo assim? Acredito que solucione seu problema.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$0 -f
    RewriteRule ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|swf)$ /public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Ainda não testei, mas gostaria também de preservar a estrutura do htaccess que eu postei antes, esse vai fazer isso? Obrigado!